# Elegant way to mask out intervals between events containing nan in numpy/pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Suppose I have some data containing certain events and I want to measure the time between events. But sometimes I have nan values because there was no measurement. I don't want to include those intervals since I don't really know what happened there.

For instance, given:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
```

I want to get back `[4, 5]` because the interval between the first set of ones is 4 indices, the interval between the second set has nans and is thus ignored, and the interval between the third and fourth ones is 5 indices. `[4, nan, 5]` would also be acceptable as an output.

I can do the following:

```
a_mod = a.copy()
a_mod[np.isnan(a)] = -1e9  # some value I know is larger than my interval will ever be
a_sum = np.cumsum(a_mod)
a_sum_pts = a_sum[a == 1]
mask = np.diff(a_sum_pts) > 0
events = np.where(a == 1)[0]
intervals = np.diff(events)
good_intervals = intervals[mask]
```

And that does indeed give me the answer I want. But it feels like a horrific hack. Is there a better way to do this? Maybe something in pandas?

Comment: To be clear: if your data was [0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1] you would want [2,1,3] as output?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 2):

Try simply

```
idx, = np.where(a==1)
nanidx, = np.where(np.isnan(a))

intervals = np.diff(idx)
good_intervals = np.delete(intervals, np.searchsorted(idx, nanidx)-1)
```

This simply looks up where the 1s are and where the `nan`s are, then deletes the intervals which contain `nan`.

The `-1` on `searchsorted` accounts for the shift of `np.diff`; as a minor caveat, this code does not work correctly if there are `nan`s before the first `1` (although this is easily remedied).

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`np.ufunc.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) to find out which segments include nan, and mask them out:

```
>>> idx, = np.where(a == 1)
>>> mask = np.logical_or.reduceat(np.isnan(a), idx)[:-1]
>>> np.diff(idx)[~mask]
array([4, 5])
```

This will perform linearly, i.e. `O(n)`.

Comment: I love the logic of this one, but I'm clocking it at ~2x slower than @nneonneo 's answer. Thanks for introducing me to `reduceat`, though! Another hidden gem in numpy.